# Why do Americans say ‘tuna fish’?

Tags: american-english

I mean, it’s not like there is a tuna vegetable or some kind of non-fish animal also named *tuna* that the fish can be confused with.

Comment: Er, a fish is an animal. But I get what you meant. ;) And to add a non-serious answer, the tunafish we get from the store tastes so little like fish that we probably wouldn't realize what it was if it wasn't on the packaging.

Comment: @MrHen, and 'fish' is the worst taxonomic term there is. Can't find the quote but there is something from Stephen Gould about "there is no such thing as a fish"

Comment: Who said we did?

Comment: For the same reason we say "cheddar cheese"  ;)

Comment: Well, obviously it's so people don't get confused thinking that Americans are always tuning their musical instruments.

Comment: @Kevin - americans say chedder cheese in the hope that you will believe them that their stuff is cheese.

Comment: Of course, “tuna” **IS** a fruit http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tuna

Comment: Most Americans do not say "tuna fish" (e.g. [Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=tuna%2Ctuna+fish&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=0)).  Most commonly it is used when talking to children.

Comment: "You can tune a file system, but you can't tuna fish." BSD 4.2 man page for tunefs

Comment: @mgb: I wouldn't be so sure about the lack of confusion: [Chicken of the Sea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_of_the_Sea#Popular_references).

Comment: @mgb - At least we can spell cheddar.

Comment: @Kevin - if only you could make it ;-) ps. Real cheese shouldn't bend, or come in a spray can !

Comment: @mgb.  Don't know where you were eating, but the cheddar I use doesn't bend or come in a spray can.

Comment: @Kevin - Houston, where assault rifles are compulsory but Brie is banned

Comment: @Kevin - Do you know where Cheddar is?

Comment: @Calum.  In my fridge, of course ;)  Or did you mean the village in England?

Comment: I think it's versus tuna sandwich, tuna salad, tuna flavor, a can of tuna. Tuna is almost always used for the meat/taste of that fish, while if you add "fish" you mean the sea animal made of tuna.

Comment: Saying "tuna fish" is like ordering a "ham pig" sandwich, or asking for a "banana fruit"

Comment: The use of tuna fish versus tuna is used more in the southern states than other areas of the country.

Comment: Proper pronunciation is **tunafish** rather than **tuna fish**.

Comment: Tuna fish ATM machine pizza pie added bonus end result

Comment: @nohat a) I've never heard of a tuna cactus, b) knowing that tuna cactus is native to tropical America it makes sense for those in the region to clarify *which* tuna they are referring to - although I can't imagine a tuna cactus sandwich tasting very good, it's good to be specific. I think you might actually have hit on the answer, certainly one I'd rather accept... care to post it as one?

Comment: None of the answers actually address the OP's question about why. Not to say that it is possible, just that they didn't bother. Presumably in non AmE situations, there is only 'tuna'. Does OED give 'tunafish' as 'chiefly American' and some quotes from the 19thc?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I agree with you that it does seem redundant.  However, this is common with other kinds of fish as well.  Many people say "codfish" instead of "cod".  Here is a [recipe](http://www.cooks.com/rec/doc/0,1717,152174-240196,00.html) for "trout fish" croquets.

This convention has important meaning to a huge number of fish names: catfish, lionfish, swordfish, sunfish, cowfish, etc.

Also, it provides extra clarification for someone who wouldn't know what a "tuna" or a "cod" is otherwise.  Anyone learning English as a second language will probably learn the meaning of "fish" early on, but may not know the more specific names.

Comment: Apart from swordfish - which I suppose does need extra context I  only every heard it for tuna. There is `Lutefisk` but that's the dish not the fish

Comment: Many names for fish have alternate, often older meanings in English, *e.g.*, cod (meaning "bag"), trout (meaning "curdle" or "coagulate"), sardine (a precious stone), carp (meaning "discourse"), and obviously cat/lion/sword/sun/cow/snapper/flounder/monk/sole.

Comment: @Esultanik: wow, four new (to me) meanings in one comment!  I hope you're not joking.

Comment: @TimLymington: No joke! Etymology is Serious Business!  Some of those meanings have been obsolesced, though, so you may not want to add them to your everyday lexicon.

Comment: -1 Have to disagree. Plus, *cat*, *lion*, *sword*, *sun*, or *cow* are not parts of a phrase with 'fish' but integral prefixes. So, you can't ever just say *cat*, *lion*, ... the without *fish* to mean that. It's not that *fish* provides extra (redundant) clarification, it is *tuna* that modifies *fish*. There are contexts where you are talking about *fish* and want to mention a certain type, say, *tuna* -- here, the adjective is a contextual addition, not the subject per se. More in favor of *tuna fish* if this were not a comment.

Comment: @Esultanik It appears that _cod_ (the fish) and _cod_ (the bag) are different words, homographs (and homophones). I know of _sard_; this and _sardine_ also have different etymologies. As do your two _carp_'s. It would be better to explain this than to say 'Many names for fish have alternate, often older meanings in English'.

Comment: You logic is flawed. If you take the "fish" away from the other fish you claim are relevant, you're left with *cat, lion, sword, sun and cow*, none of which have any relevant to fish. If you take "fish" away from "Tuna fish", you're left with the very same species... Tuna. Clearly, the "fish" in "tuna fish" adds no value, as there is no other kind of tuna.

Comment: While the question is a good one, the OP should bear in mind that just saying "tuna" is correct, too, so the "fish" as colloquially included may be redundant, but it's also not necessary. In other words, both of these are equally correct: (1) I'll take a tuna sandwich on rye. (2) I'll take a tuna fish sandwich on rye. (If you want to be even more colloquial, you'd omit both "fish" and "sandwich" and say, "I'll take a tuna on rye.")

Answer (score 16):

Tuna or cod is not always fish, just as cheddar is not always cheese.

In both cases, it distinguishes the primary item from items merely flavored with the item.

Tuna fish is almost always the meat of the Tuna. Seldom is it the fish itself alive and/or whole; for those uses, "tuna" is used without "fish." Tuna salad is a mixture of tuna and mayonaise, and often some diced pickles and/or onions.  Tuna sandwiches are sandwiches using tuna, and can be grilled or tuna salad. Tuna crackers are tuna flavored crackers. Tuna alone also can be a crude aphorism for female genitalia.

Cheddar is both the cheese, and the city where the recipe originates. Several cheeses are likewise named for their place of origin, most notably swiss, münster, and berkswell. But cheddar crackers are not made of cheddar, nor do they originate in cheddar, but are flavored with cheddar cheese. Cheddar spread is mostly cheddar cheese,

Cod can be the fish, or the meat of the fish; a cod dinner is seldom just codfish, but usually also chips (fries) and/or hushpuppies (corn fritters). The USS Cod is a submarine. Cod is also an extremely common acronym, most commonly for "Cash on Delivery." Codpiece is a male pubic covering; cod at one point was slang for the scrotum, so codfish was a way of ensuring one was talking about fish and not men's genitals.

Speaking of corn fritters, I've never met a fritter that wasn't made with cornmeal; I'm TOLD they exist... Likewise, most have also wheat flour and whole kernel corn. It's another case of a term that at first appears to be redundant, but really isn't.

Comment: hushpuppies definitely need more adornment, had there been no `(cord fritters)` I would have thought that it would be made from a young canine.

Comment: It really depends on the word. We don't call it Champagne wine or Cologne perfume. You might call it cheddar cheese out of context but if you asked for a slice of Cheddar, it would be unlikely you wanted a strip of the city! I never knew that tuna was also a cactus fruit; to me it is always the edible flesh of one of the types of fish called tuna (bluefin, yellowfin, etc.) unless it is disambiguated by context.

Comment: But 'tuna fish bake' also exists as a usage. 'Tuna bake' is used because it is more snappy.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There's also the issue that the other uses of Tuna don't make much sense in a bake, tho' I've seen college students bake crackers into casseroles...

Comment: I've only ever heard Americans call it a "tuna fish sandwich", never a "tuna sandwich".

Comment: I have, @Bohemian. I've even done so myself, and my passport says "US Citizen"...

Comment: @Bohemian One of the things people often forget is that American English isn't one monolithic thing. If you go to different regions even sometimes in the same state, they refer to things by different names. FWIW, where I grew up people used both interchangeably.

Comment: This logic is just silly. Cheddar sandwich will never mean bread with "the city where the recipe originates". Tuna sandwich will never mean a sandwich with "the fish itself alive and/or whole".

Answer (score 12):

As a fisherman I can tell you that:

"Tuna-fish" refers to the stuff in a can that is used to make tuna-fish salads or similar items. It is typically albacore.

"Tuna" refers to the the meat in steak form and served raw (as sushi/sashimi), grilled, or pan seared. It is typically yellow-fin or blue-fin.

Other fish such as catfish, swordfish, lionfish, etc. obviously need the fish qualifier as a cat, sword, and lion as stand alone words are completely different things. Also, while there is a tuna cactus (it is the fruit part) it most commonly referred to as the prickly pear cactus.

Below the first picture is "tuna-fish" and the second picture is "tuna". Tuna is perhaps the only fish where preparations are this vastly different.

[image: "Tuna-fish"]

[image: Tuna]

Comment: I agree with your assessment of the use of "tuna fish" vs "tuna". But what are your thoughts on why one is called "tuna fish"? I never hear canned chicken referred to as "chicken bird".

Comment: Only because I've never heard of the distinction before, can you supply dictionary definitions which support this differentiation?

Comment: @Mitch, it's in the OED. See my answer below for the entry, if you don't have access.

Comment: @Mitch I'm not sure any dictionary would support it, the distinction is colloquial. If I told you to come over for a tuna dinner, and you were expecting what is in the bottom picture but received the top picture....

Comment: It's far from the only fish with such divergent serving options. Salmon has the same -  salmon steaks, canned salmon, salmon jerky, wet-smoked salmon, dry-smoked salmon, salmon soaked in seal oil, smoked salmon softened in seal oil... Some of those are hard for white-folk to do, but are standard in Yupiq and Inupiaq communities. I've never encountered tuna in seal oil.

Answer (score 6):

*Tuna* is used to mean the fish, and the flesh of that fish (which is also called *tuna fish*).

*Tuna* is also the edible fruit of a cactus, or the name of that cactus.

Answer (score 5):

Just to back up [Skooba's correct answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/288762/171986), the OED entry for “[tuna fish](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/207418#eid17467476)” is precisely

> **tuna fish** *n.* the flesh of the tunny as food.

with its earliest citation given as

> > 1917 M[ary] Green [*Better Meals* [*for Less Money*]](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.hn1pf2) [xvi. 130](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.hn1pf2;view=1up;seq=140) (*heading*)
> >
> > > [image]

[Wikipedia's article on tuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuna#Fishing_industry) similarly glosses

> When tuna is canned and packaged for sale, the product is sometimes called **tuna fish**.

noting that the US legally restricts “white meat tuna” to referencing albacore and not yellowfin, bluefin, &c.

**It's also worth noting that [Albert Halfhill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_P._Halfhill) & his followers completely altered the flavor of tuna** while trying to keep his cannery in business through a collapse of the sardine fishery off California in 1903. He tried to reverse engineer some Italian tuna canning methods, removing the fish oil and replacing it with salad oil, but went on to treat the result with compressed steam. The white meat that process produced—the stuff Americans mean when they talk about “tuna fish” and a very different thing from tuna steak or sashimi—had such a chicken-like consistency that tuna exploded in popularity in the US and [even a century later still famously got confused with chicken on national television](https://people.com/tv/jessica-simpson-chicken-of-the-sea-meme/).

Answer (score 3):

I think of *tuna fish* as the chopped up stuff in a can.

*Tuna*, on the other hand, I think of as whole fish.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason **cheese** gets appended to **Cheddar** much more often than to **Double Gloucester**, **Brie**, **Camembert**, **Wensleydale** etc. is because it's the most common type. The archetypal cheese, as **cod** is the archetypal fish. (and I've heard *codfish*, but not *haddockfish* or *salmonfish*). And in UK at least, tuna is the most common canned fish.

As an archetype, it often thus gets to represent not just it's own particular type, but *all* cheeses. After a restaurant meal I might ask for some Cheddar Cheese - I may not really care which cheese I get, but most likely if they have *any*, they'll have that. If they *do* have alternatives I'll doubtless be offered them, but I'd be irritated by a waiter who included cheesecake in the offerings after I'd asked for Cheddar Cheese.

Comment: Why so much cheese in your comment? What about the tuna?

Comment: I like cheese more than tuna